# How to create a sales graph (using Recat JS or npm)

Tags: reactjs, graph, e-commerce

I want to create a sales graph (using Recat JS or npm) for admin dashboard for an ecommerce webiste. So is there any pre made npm and how to use it?

I have tried searching on Google but didn't find that. Hence I was looking for a npm for building sales graph using React JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of packages you can use to create charts on React

Here are some of them:-

1. [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2)
2. [react-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-charts)
3. [nivo](https://dev.to/syakirurahman/7-best-react-chart-graph-libraries-how-to-use-them-with-demo-32ak)
4. [FusionCharts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/sales-dashboard-using-react-framework-fusioncharts/)

Check those and see which fits your needs, if you have more specific needs can you also share them?